Why doesn't work my custom shader in CesiumJS?
I’m creating my custom shader to make a dotted line, since PolylineDash moves and scales when the camera moves. Why my shader is not working and who can tell me how to achieve my goal?
let countyBorderPrimitive = new GroundPolylinePrimitive({
                    geometryInstances: new GeometryInstance({
                        geometry: new GroundPolylineGeometry({
                            positions: Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(newBorPos),
                            width: 3,
                        })
                    }),
                    show: stores.ggStore.visibleStatus,
                    appearance: new PolylineMaterialAppearance({
                        translucent: false,
                        material: Material.fromType('Color', {
                            color: new Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                        }),
                        vertexShaderSource: `
                        attribute vec3 position3DHigh;
                        attribute vec3 position3DLow;
                        attribute vec2 st;
                        attribute float batchId;

                        uniform mat4 modelViewProjection;
                        uniform vec3 eyeOffset;

                        varying vec2 v_st;
                        varying float v_batchId;

                        void main() {
                            vec4 p = czm_translateRelativeToEye(position3DHigh, position3DLow, eyeOffset);
                            gl_Position = modelViewProjection * p;
                            v_st = st;
                            v_batchId = batchId;
                        }
                        `,
                        fragmentShaderSource: `
                            varying vec2 v_st;
                            varying float v_batchId;
                            uniform vec4 color;
                            uniform float dashLength;
                                    
                            void main() {
                                float d = fract(v_st.s * dashLength);
                                if (d < 0.5) {
                                    discard;
                                }
                                gl_FragColor = color;
                            }
                        `
                    })
                });
                cesium.scene.groundPrimitives.add(countyBorderPrimitive);

Create Shader, switch type material
